# Only run a task when a set of other tasks do not produce change

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

How to configure a playbook when a set of tasks run successfully but none od them produce any change, it will cause one other task to be run. If even one of the set of task produce a change, that one other task will not be run. However, without having to list all registered variables of the tasks in the condition of the last task.

So, something like this:

```
task:
︙
- name: task 1
︙
︙

- name: task 20
  ...

- name: to be run when task 1-20 all produce no change
  ...
  when: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One I can think of - but not elegant - is having each tasks in the set to notify a handler, where the handler simply `set_fact` a variable, then have a `meta: flush_handlers` after the set of task, then after that the final task simply have condition to check if the variable is not defined. Assuming this works, the issue is that `meta: flush_handlers` will trigger all notified handlers.

So, something like this:

```
task:
︙
- name: task 1
  notify: A task produce change
︙
︙

- name: task 20
  notify: A task produce change
  ...

- meta: flush_handlers

- name: to be run when task 1-20 all produce no change
  ...
  when: changingtask is not defined

handler:
- name: A task produce change
  set_fact:
    changingtask: true
```

Any better suggestions?

Comment: why do you mean its not elegant solution..i dont see others....